# Autofac and MVC integration: Register Type per API Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm working with .Net 4.5, ASP.NET MVC 5, and the NuGet packages:
Autofac 3.5.2
Autofac ASP.NET Web Api 5 Integration 3.0.0-rc1

I have 2 different implementations of an interface:

```
public class MemoryStreamService : IStreamService { ... }
public class HttpStreamService : IStreamService { ... }
```

Also another concrete class that uses the interface by constructor injection:

```
public class MainService : IMainService 
{
    public MainService(IStreamService streamService) { ... }
}
```

And I have 2 ASP.NET Web API Controllers using the main service by constructor injection too:

```
public class MemoryStreamController : ApiController 
{
    public MemoryStreamController(IMainService mainService) { ... }
}

public class HttpStreamController : ApiController 
{
    public HttpStreamController(IMainService mainService) { ... }
}
```

What I want is to use the MemoryStreamService implementation when an instance of IStreamService need to be instantiated in the context of a call to MemoryStreamController, and the HttpStreamService implementation when we are in the context of a call to the HttpStreamController.

I'm trying to accomplish that by registering the controllers and service classes in Autofac builder at Application_Start() within Global.asax.cs in the following way:

```
builder.RegisterType<MainService>().As<IMainService>();

builder.RegisterType<MemoryStreamService>()
       .As<IStreamService>()
       .InstancePerApiControllerType(typeof(MemoryStreamController));

builder.RegisterType<HttpStreamService>()
       .As<IStreamService>()
       .InstancePerApiControllerType(typeof(HttpStreamController));

builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

But looks like the InstancePerApiControllerType() does not work for that: I'm getting always the first registered implementation Type of the IStreamService (in this sample, MemoryStreamController) for both Controllers.

How do I need to configure Autofac for getting an instance of MemoryStreamService in the context of a request handled by MemoryStreamController, and an instance of HttpStreamService for calls hadled by HttpStreamController?

**EDIT**: If I weren't using dependency injection for the controllers, this is what I would do:

```
public class MemoryStreamController : ApiController 
{
    public MemoryStreamController() 
    {
        this.mainService = new MainService(new MemoryStreamService());
    }
}

public class HttpStreamController : ApiController 
{
    public HttpStreamController()
    {
        this.mainService = new MainService(new HttpStreamService());
    }
}
```

So my question can be read as: How can I achieve the same by using Autofac for registering both my controllers and all my services?

Comment: You will want to use a named registration see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262704/autofac-how-to-resolve-interface-based-on-service-where-its-passed-to

Comment: There is an FAQ about this sort of situation in the Autofac docs: http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html

Comment: Hi @MattS, thanks for your comment. I could register MemoryStreamService and HttpStreamService with a name per each one, but in my scenario I have a class (MainService) between the 2 top level classes (the Controllers) and the low level implementations (would be the named services). And the controllers are the ones that determine the type of the low level implementations needed for the common interface (IStreamService). I don't see how can I do that with named registrations.

Comment: Hi @TravisIllig, thanks for your comment. I've read all the article , but seems like all the solutions there only deal with direct relationships between the context classes (the controllers, in my scenario) and the injected components (the Http and Memory services). But I have one more layer between them (the MainService).

Comment: Consider applying the concept further - you may need two named registrations for MainService, too. Or, again, as the FAQ mentions, consider a redesign. In any case, the FAQ explains the pattern for unwinding this - it's up to you to try to apply the pattern.

Comment: Hi @TravisIllig, I got to a solution following your advice regarding using 2 named registrations for MainService, just posted the answer that's working for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've followed @TravisIllig advice (thanks!) and:
1) used named registrations for both "stream services",
2) used 2 named registrations for MainService, they differ in the type of stream service they can take as parameter
3) registered the controllers by specifying each named MainService as appropriate.

```
builder.RegisterType<MemoryStreamService>().Named<IStreamService>("memoryService");
builder.RegisterType<HttpStreamService>().Named<IStreamService>("httpService");

builder
    .RegisterType<MainService>()
    .As<IMainService>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IStreamService>("memoryService"))
    .Named<IMainService>("mainServiceForMemoryStreams");

builder
    .RegisterType<MainService>()
    .As<IMainService>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IStreamService>("httpService"))
    .Named<IMainService>("mainServiceForHttpStreams");

// This is for registering the other controllers of my API
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// Manually registers controllers that need an specific instance of IStreamService.
// These registrations needs to be placed after the "RegisterApiControllers()" call in order to Autofac to perform the desired injections.
builder.RegisterType<MemoryStreamController>()
       .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IMainService>("mainServiceForMemoryStreams"));
builder.RegisterType<HttpStreamController>()
       .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IMainService>("mainServiceForHttpStreams"));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this. First you register your services as named:

```
builder.RegisterType<MemoryStreamService>()
   .Named<IStreamService>("MemoryStreamService")
   .InstancePerApiControllerType(typeof(MemoryStreamController));

builder.RegisterType<HttpStreamService>()
   .Named<IStreamService>("HttpStreamService")
   .InstancePerApiControllerType(typeof(HttpStreamController));
```

And then you register a func factory that can resolve the correct service based on a name. Like this:

```
builder.Register<Func<string, IStreamService>>(c =>
        {
            var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return service =>
            {
                return context.ResolveNamed<IStreamService>(service);
            };
        });
```

And then in the controllers when you are resolving the `IMainService` you can inject a `Func<string, IMainService>` (the first argument in the constructor for `MainService` needs to be string). This way you can pass along the name of the service you would like to resolve. Like this:

```
public class MemoryStreamController : ApiController 
{
    private IMainService _service;

    public MemoryStreamController(Func<string, IMainService> mainService) 
    {
        _service = mainService("MemoryStreamService")
    }
}
```

And then in the constructor for `MainService` you invoke the func factory with the type name that is injected. Like this:

```
public MainService(string type, Func<string, IStreamService> factory)
{
    _service = factory(type);
}
```

Comment: Hi @peco, thanks for your answer! Your solution will make it work and it's helpful, but I was looking to a solution that maintains all the wiring in the Autofac registrations and doesn't pollute my classes with new constructor parameters.